# the react-native-reanimated is not working

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated

i have a code that write with react-native-reanimated but now because of react native version it's not working so what should i do , i have go and tru to install react-native-reanimated@2.3.0-alpha.2 but i I didn't succeed . please any one have solve it or have a simple way to install it

[when i install it gives me this :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfQBr.png)

:[and when i remove it like then](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CSRq.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using react native v0.65. and because of that you can only use [reanimated v2.3.0alpha3](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/releases/tag/2.3.0-alpha.3). after doing that close your metro bundler and then rebuild the project using `npm run android`

Comment: thanks for answering , i try that but it didnt work . for real idk if it does not work because the  reanimated v2.3.0alpha3. or i installed it in a wrong way .but i tried and it give the same error .

Comment: You probably didn't follow the instruction correctly